# String index out of range?

Tags: java

I keep getting this error with my code:

> "exception in thread main java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception string index out of range"

What is the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Compress { 

public static void main(String[] args)  
{ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string: "); 
    String compress = scan.nextLine();
    int count = 0; 

    for (count = 0; count <= compress.length(); count++) 
    { 
        while( count +1  < compress.length() && compress.charAt(count) == compress.charAt(count + 1)) 
        { 
            count = count + 1; 
        } 
        System.out.print(count + "" + compress.charAt(count));
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The string indexes run from `0` to `length - 1`, so you are running off the end of the string `compress`.  Change your `for` loop condition from

```
for (count = 0; count <= compress.length(); count++)
```

to

```
for (count = 0; count < compress.length(); count++)
```

This way, when `count` reaches `compress.length()`, then the `for` loop is stopped before that index is used.

Answer (score 1):

The Index range from `0 to length-1`. Try to use:-

```
for (count = 0; count < compress.length(); count++)
```

instead of

```
for (count = 0; count <= compress.length(); count++)
```